# window.onload doesn't work all the time. Why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on changing the src attribute to change the image in javascript. I was using `window.onload = function()` and my code wasn't working. I decided to take out `window.onload` and miraculously my code worked. The `src` attribute changed the image on the page.

A lot of literature I read boasted about window.onload function as though it was absolutely necessary to load a web page in order for other code to work. I'm confused because it didn't work for me in this instance. And I recalled a recent college assignment I was working on that didn't work with window.onload function. Here is the script I used with and without window.onload function. Can somebody give me an explanation for this oddity.

```
  window.onload = function(){
  function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "people5.png";
  };
  };
  </script>
  </head>
 <body>
 <img id = "myImg" src="people1.png" width="240" height="240" alt="logo"/>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Now without window.onload

```
  function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "people5.png";
  };

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <img id = "myImg" src="people1.png" width="240" height="240" alt="logo"/>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function myFunction(){
      document.getElementById("myImg").src = "people5.png";
    };
    window.onload = myFunction;
```

or

```
 <body onload='myFunction()' >
```

Comment: I guess I got a ways to go. I thank you for your answer even though I'm still a bit confused with onclick. Is it outside the scope of myFunction. How. What makes a handler not accessible to a function. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function(){
  function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "people5.png";
  };
};
```

`myFunction()` in `window.onload` is local to the anonymous function.when you declare `myFunction` outside `window.onload`, it is defined in global scope and is therefore accessible to `onclick` event

Comment: I understand you saying that myFunction() is local and window.onload is global. Does that mean that a global variable or function can't work inside a local function. I thought global scope take precedence over local scope. I'm not clear on you answer.

Comment: @swydell the problem mainly is `onClick="myFunction()"` ,for onclick to work here , `myFunction()` should be  accessible to it but since `myFunction()` is local to the `window.onload` handler ,it can't be accessed by onclick. side note: globals are always accessible in function scope.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is the best to use event lister so you don't overwrite onload function.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        console.log('page is fully loaded1');
    });

    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        console.log('page is fully loaded2');
    });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event